# Adding query parameters when using Gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm learning REST API development with go and cant figure out how to go about getting user specific documents.
My use case is a typical get request that can fetch all the documents in a slice. However I want to be able to only fetch documents belonging to a user based on their ID such that a user of ID: 1 should not be able to get documents belonging to user of ID:2. How can I go about adding the userID parameters with gorilla mux and fetch desired data.

Document struct

```
type Document struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    DocName  string `json:"documentName"`
    DocOwner string `json:"documentOwner"`
    UserID string `json:"userID"`
}
```

Documents slice

```
sampleDocuments = []Document{
        {Id: "1", DocName: "Identity card", DocOwner: "Beans",UserID: "1"},
        {Id: "2", DocName: "Drivers License", DocOwner: "Kal",UserID: "2"},
        {Id: "3", DocName: "Pilots License", DocOwner: "Jay",UserID: "2"},
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out as demonstrated below.

```
//Get documents belonging to a user based on userID
func getDocuments(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Create an empty struct to hold users documents
    var userDocs []Document
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    userid := vars["userID"]
    
        // filter using user id
        for _, d := range sampleDocuments {
            if d.UserID == userid {
                userDocs = append(userDocs, d)
          
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(userDocs)
```

}

Request url should look something like this:

```
"...../documents/{userID}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use a query parameter as stated in the title of the question.  The Gorilla Mux does not play a role using query parameters.

Call the [Request.FormValue](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormValue) method to get the query parameter. Filter using the value of the parameter.

```
func documentHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var result []Document
    id := r.FormValue("ID")
    if id == "" {
        // Return all documents when no user id specified
        result = sampleDocuments
    } else {
        // filter using user id
        for _, d := range sampleDocuments {
            if d.UserID == id {
                result = append(result, d)
            }
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```